# apache2 vhost doesn't always respond

Tags: apache2, webserver

I added the following virtualhost (i have the default *:80 one of course) to my apache:

Listen 8989
NameVirtualHost 10.8.0.1:8989

```
<VirtualHost 10.8.0.1:8989>
    DocumentRoot /var/crib
    ServerName Thor
    ServerAlias Thor

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/crib/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from 10.8.0.0/255.255.255.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But sometimes it doesn't always respond... so I'm wondering what could be the problem?

I don't even know where to look... 10.8.0.1 is my VPN address. The virtual host 80 works perfectly and am wondering if my configuration has any flaws

Comment: Does the name `Thor` resolve in DNS?

Comment: No it doesn't. SHould I replace it with the ip address instead?

Comment: Are you planning on having >1 virtual host (diff. hostnames) on that same IP and port? if not, remove the NameVirtualHost option and ServerName and ServerAlias.  If you are going to do name based hosting, leave all of that, but use a name that resolves in DNS.  You can just put something in /etc/hosts on the local system for testing, but eventually you'll have to get a real hostname for other people to access your site/application.

Comment: Oh I got it. I don't have access to my server right now to try this out, but I'm wondering if this is what's causing the issue?. And I've also realized that oddly Webmin does the same thing... but it's not even running in Apache but using its own miniserver (on port 10000 and 20000 for usermin)... And the apache vhost *:80 works **always** with no single problem...

Comment: It might not be the root cause, but it helps to rule it out if you can.

Comment: Thank you very much AJ, I will fix this out this week end and get back to you :) Would be nice if you propose this as an answer so if it helps I'll accept it :).

Comment: Sure...I'm not convinced that this is the only problem.  Try it first, and we'll see what other problems become apparent after that.

Comment: Sorted. Thank you. Told ya, propose as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you planning on having >1 virtual host (diff. hostnames) on that same IP and port? if not, remove the NameVirtualHost option and ServerName and ServerAlias.  If you are going to do name based hosting, leave all of that, but use a name that resolves in DNS.  You can just put something in /etc/hosts on the local system for testing, but eventually you'll have to get a real hostname for other people to access your site/application.